# Razor View - jQuery .val() is updating some components visually -- but not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I have a search feature built into a page that hits an API to get a list of items if a user chooses to search instead of manually enter (in an attempt to get some clean data). I have the first column of said table set to call a JavaScript function onclick. That function looks similar to this:

```
function loadDataFromTable(fname, lname, mname, stn, grade, school) {
        $('#StudentFirstName').val(fname);
        $('#StudentLastName').val(lname);
        if (mname !== "undefined") {
            $('#StudentMiddleName').val(mname);
        }
        else {
            $('#StudentMiddleName').val('');
        }
        $('#StudentNumber').val(stn);
        $('#Grade').val(grade);
        $('#School').val(school);
        return false;
    }
```

The associated HTML elements are all ASP.NET Core Razor View input elements. They look like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" asp-for="StudentLastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StudentLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">STN</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" asp-for="StudentNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StudentNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Grade</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" asp-for="Grade" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Grade" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="School" class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select asp-for="School" asp-items="ViewBag.SchoolList" class="form-control"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="School" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, if a user clicks on one of the links from the table, all of the values are properly passed into the function, and all of the values for First Name, Last Name, Middle Name, and STN properly update on the view. Grade and School do not update on the View, but their value attribute does update. When I submit the form after the data fills, the correct values are passed to my controller.

What I can't figure out is why the Grade and School values are not populating on the view. The only thing that stands out as different for these two are within the model they are nullable integers, whereas other fields are strings.

I have tried a mixture of .attr('value', grade), .text(grade), and .val(grade), and none of them are working. I can verify that the proper elements are being selected because if I output $('#Grade') I get the input object.

Comment: What is inside `ViewBag.SchoolList` ? or what is the rendered output for the SELECT element. Is the value of one of the option matching to the `school` param value you are passing to your js method ?

Comment: Yea, the ViewBag is just a List<SelectListItem> with Value/Text that corresponds with what school would be.